# Spring Data MongoDB template converts to wrong class

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Using Spring 5.0.6 and Spring-Data-Mongo 2.0.7, I have an issue when fetching entities being transformed into the wrong class. See the following simplified scenario:

Entity setup:

```
public class PersistableObject {
  @Id @Field("_id") private String id; 
}

@Document(collection = "myapp_user")
public class User extends PersistableObject {...}

public class RealUser extends User {...}

public class VirtualUser extends User {...}
```

So, there is a common MongoDB *collection* storing both types of `User`, discriminated by the automatically added *_class* property.

Furthermore, there is a Repository into which the MongoTemplate is injected.

```
@Autowired 
private org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate template;
```

Everything fine, so far. Now, if I want to fetch all documents that contain a `RealUser`, I could call this

```
template.findAll(RealUser.class)
```

I'd expect the template to find all documents that have the discriminator property  *_class* set to `com.myapp.domain.RealUser`.

But this doesn't work as expected. I even get all `VirtualUser`s, as well, put into objects of type `RealUser` with all VirtualUser-specific properties  missing, and all RealUser-specific properties set to `null`.

Furthermore, when I go and save a `User`, which is actually a `VirtualUser` in MongoDB, but has been squeezed into a `RealUser` class, Spring would change the `_class`-property to the wrong type, *magically* converting a `VirtualUser` into a `RealUser`.

So both methods here would load the entire collection and squeeze all objects into the specified class, even if it is the wrong one:

```
 template.findAll(VirtualUser.class)
 template.findAll(RealUser.class)
```

This behavior is probably not desired, or if so, then it is extremely misleading and harmful. You can easily shred your whole data with this.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1981) at Spring's Jira. Find Olivers comment below:

> The method actually works as expected but I agree that we need to
>   improve the JavaDoc. The method is basically specified as "Load the
>   documents the given type is configured to persisted in and map all of
>   them (hence the name) to the given type". The type given to it is not
>   used as a type mapping criteria at the same time. Every restriction
>   you want to apply on the documents returned needs to be applied
>   through a Query instance, which exposes a ….restrict(…) method that
>   allows to only select documents that carry type information.
>
> The reason that findAll works the way it works is that generally
>   speaking – i.e. without an inheritance scenario in place – we need to
>   be able to read all documents, even if they don't carry any type
>   information. Assume a collection with documents representing people
>   that have not been written using Spring Data. If a
>   findAll(Person.class) applied type restrictions, the call would return
>   no documents even if there were documents present. Unfortunately we
>   don't know if the collection about to be queried carries type
>   information. In fact, some documents might carry type information,
>   some might not. The only way to reasonably control this, is to let the
>   user decide, which she can by either calling Query.restrict(…) or not.
>   The former selects documents with type information only, the latter.
>
> As I said, I totally see that the JavaDoc might be misleading here.
>   I'm gonna use this ticket to improve on that. Would love to hear if
>   the usage of Query.restict(…) allows you to achieve what you want.